# Layout height decrease from the bottom

Tags: android, layout

I' m trying to reduce a linear layout height in the code, it works but it decreases from the bottom not the top.
Here is my code :

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/pension_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/linearborder"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:weightSum="100">
```

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 600);
    pl.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Mention the layout height in dp. If you mention 40 dp you layout will be exactly 40dp. dp refers to density pixels.

Comment: yes. you mention it in your java code. But it is recommended to mention the same in xml as UI and logic will be separate. Any changes you make to ui will not effect you logic in .java file

Comment: The thing is even when i change layout height in the xml file it decreases from the bottom, i need it to decrease from the top.

Comment: android:layout_marginTop="mention dp". Use this to set you layout to whatever position from top. Mention your layout height in android:layout_height="yourdp". I do not understand what you mean decrease. Does it refer to the space or you want layout height to be something.

Comment: i mean when it's reduced the bottom part is reduced not the top one you got me?
 top |----------|Bottom (but in vertical) when i reduce it's the bottom which is reduced

Comment: When we set the height, It sets it from top and cut the other part from bottom. I exactly need its inverse. 

100dp image 
height 50dp 
start from middle to end - instead of top to middle.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same issue. In my case, what I did is -

just rotate the view in X direction

```
xView.setRotationX(180);
```

Then set height using layoutParam.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) 
xView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 300;
xView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

It will cut from the top.

Hope this will help.